# How do I read in columns from a file with R

Tags: r, dataset

I have files of the following format (just numbers, nothing else):

```
12.5 18.75 18.75 37.5 31.25 31.25 
13.6 12.8 15.6 32.6 41 26.4 
13.6 12.8 15.6 32.6 41 26.4 
9.375 7.8125 11.71875 46.09375 36.71875 17.1875
.
.
.
```

Many more lines. Is there a simple way I can read the 6 columns into separate R vectors for further processing?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the help files for `read.table()` and this [FAQ site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/inputdata_R.htm) for inputing data into R.

Comment: It's not clear if you have many separate files that you are trying to read into R or only one file

Comment: I have only one file to be read. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
mydf = read.table(text="
 12.5 18.75 18.75 37.5 31.25 31.25 
 13.6 12.8 15.6 32.6 41 26.4 
 13.6 12.8 15.6 32.6 41 26.4 
 9.375 7.8125 11.71875 46.09375 36.71875 17.1875
 ", header=F)

mydf
      V1      V2       V3       V4       V5      V6
1 12.500 18.7500 18.75000 37.50000 31.25000 31.2500
2 13.600 12.8000 15.60000 32.60000 41.00000 26.4000
3 13.600 12.8000 15.60000 32.60000 41.00000 26.4000
4  9.375  7.8125 11.71875 46.09375 36.71875 17.1875
```

Basically, copy all the lines, then type following in the R terminal (in between you will need to paste all the lines by pressing shift-insert):

```
mydf = read.table(text="
<paste your lines here>
", header=F)
```

mydf will be a data.frame:

```
str(mydf)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ V1: num  12.5 13.6 13.6 9.38
 $ V2: num  18.75 12.8 12.8 7.81
 $ V3: num  18.8 15.6 15.6 11.7
 $ V4: num  37.5 32.6 32.6 46.1
 $ V5: num  31.2 41 41 36.7
 $ V6: num  31.2 26.4 26.4 17.2
```

You can access each element by commands like following:

```
mydf$V1
[1] 12.500 13.600 13.600  9.375
```

For reading from file:

```
read.table(filename, header = FALSE, sep = "")
```

Can also use:

```
read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
read.delim(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
read.delim2(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

For help, give command:

```
?read.table
```

Comment: Thanks for the input rnso, but I need to read the data from a file, inputting it manually is not an option in my case.

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation and that's why it doesn't allow me to "vote". :) When I reach 15, I'll be sure to up-vote. Until then - THANK YOU AND GOD BLESS YOU.

Answer (score 3):

The way R works, you should read them into a matrix or data frame and access the variables (columns) of that as needed, for example, via `with` or through the use of `$` or `[`. See `?with`, `?"$"` and `?"["`.

Nearly nineteen times out of twenty, I'd just use `read.table` on that data (or maybe `read.delim`) to put it in a data frame. Since it doesn't seem to have variable labels there, I'd then use `colnames` to set up the names of the variables in the data frame.

Most of the remaining fraction of the time I'd probably use `as.matrix` around that to put it in a matrix. Once in a while I'd `matrix(scan(),...)` instead.

Comment: What code I'd write would depend on where it was stored, or if I was pasting it in, etc, and even how big it was.... and this isn't really a "write a program for me" site, but if it were, you'd have to supply much more information to make that feasible. There's examples of use of functions at the end of every help page in R, and if you search the internet (say via google) you can find innumerable examples of `read.table` and the other functions in use. `mydata = read.table(<filename>,header=FALSE)` should work, if you put the full address of the filename in (the way R filenames work).

Comment: Or try `mydata = read.table(file.choose(),header=FALSE)` ... but for some sets of data I wouldn't use either of those.